# Perform select Query on selectedDate of CalendarExtender

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I want to perform select query on selectedDate value of CalendarExtender in asp.net.
I have one dummy button (visible=false) and perform button click event on calendar Extendar with the help of

> OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkDate"

and javascript function "checkDate" is

> 

```
<script type="text/javascript">
>         function checkDate(sender, args) {
>             var Clientdate = sender._selectedDate;
>             __doPostBack('Button1', '');
>         } </script>
```

and code behind file on button click event is

```
> protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             //txtDate.Text = Convert.ToString(CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate);
>             String cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
>             using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
>             {
>                 gvAlreadyAllocated.Visible = true;
>                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Date,EmpName,TimeSlot,Topic,ClassroomNo from tblTimeSlotDetails where
> Date=@CalenderDate", con);
>                 con.Open();
>                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CalenderDate",);
>                 using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
>                 {
>                     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>                     dt.Columns.Add("Date");
>                     dt.Columns.Add("Name");
>                     dt.Columns.Add("TimeSlot");
>                     dt.Columns.Add("Topic");
>                     dt.Columns.Add("Classroom Number");
> 
>                     while (rdr.Read())
>                     {
>                         DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
> 
>                         dataRow["Date"] = Convert.ToString(rdr["Date"]);
> 
>                         dataRow["Name"] = rdr["Empname"];
>                         dataRow["TimeSlot"] = rdr["TimeSlot"];
>                         dataRow["Topic"] = rdr["Topic"];
>                         dataRow["Classroom Number"] = rdr["ClassroomNo"];
>                         dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
>                     }
>                     //gvAlreadyAllocated.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Already allocate data for this Date";
>                     gvAlreadyAllocated.DataSource = dt;
>                     gvAlreadyAllocated.DataBind();
> 
>                     //gvAlreadyAllocated.DataSource = rdr;
>                     //gvAlreadyAllocated.DataBind();
>                 }
>             }
>         }
```

but how to pass value to @Calenderdate parameter?

> cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CalenderDate",);

I want to display one gridview where my selectedDate is match with date of database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the column in `date` and the `value` which you want to match

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Date,EmpName,TimeSlot,Topic,ClassroomNo from tblTimeSlotDetails where cast(Datecol as Date)=cast(@CalenderDate as Date),con
```

And value of parameter will be value of calenderextender selected date.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CalenderDate",Convert.ToString(CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate));
```